# Type mismatch: the type referenced in object not the same as the one defined in a trait that object extends?

Tags: scala

Object `O` extends a trait `T1` which has the type `C` defined.

In `T1` I want to manipulate the static data structure `stack` defined in object `O`.
but the compiler keeps on complaining

> type mismatch that found T1.this.C, require O.C

The code is like:

```
trait T1 {

 case class C(i: Int, s: String)
  def dumbAdd(i: Int, s: String) = {
    O.stack.push(C(i, s))  // type mismatch error goes here.
  }
}

object O extends T1 {

  var stack: Stack[C] = new Stack[C]

}
```

I am confused... doesn't `O` know `C` and should be the same type as the one in `T1`? 
What am I missing here?
and how can I do what I want?

*Update*

Based on one suggestion to put `C` in object `T1`, but in my real example, the object `T1` can't access to the types defined in trait `T1`. The reduced problem is as below:

```
trait T1 {

  abstract sealed class S

  case class SC extends S

  def dumbAdd(i: Int, s: String) = {
    O.stack.push(C(i, s))
  }
}

object T1 {

  case class C(i: Int, s: String)

  def tryASC {
    val scc = SC() // Here the compiler says not found value SC
  }
}

object O extends T1 {

  var stack: Stack[C] = new Stack[C]

}
```

Comment: Please add the line&caret of error messages, so we know exactly _where_ the mismatch was found.

Answer (score 6):

Nested classes belong to an *instance* of their parent class. That is, the types of `x` and `y` below are different:

```
val a = new T1 {}
val b = new T2 {}
val x = new a.C(0, "")
val y = new b.C(0, "")
```

The type of `x` is, literally, `a.C`, and the type of `y` is `b.C`.

The problem in your code is that you are referring to `C` without specifying what's the instance to which that `C` belongs to, with the end result being that they are all assumed to be from different instances.

Nested classes are useful, but difficult to use due to their very strict semantics.

Comment: Path-dependent types. One solution: put C in an `object T1`.

Comment: @pedrofurla yeah. but it seems that object T1 can't access to the type s (classes) defined in trait T1....

Comment: There is no type s defined in you example.

Comment: @pedrofurla Sorry.. the `s` is a typo. I tried to use your technique in my real code example, but I found that types defined in trait can't be accessed in the companion object.

Comment: Read my comment again. You won't need to access it in the trait because it will be in object.

Comment: @pedrofurla For clarity, I updated my post based on your suggestion, and the problem I mentioned in my previous comments is also indicated in the code sample... did I still miss something? Thanks very much,

Comment: But O.stack.push(C(i, s)) is compiling now, isn't it?